# Dispatch JavaScript event to other windows (and browsers) via flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to dispatch javascript event to other opened windows (for example I want to mute all other players, of course only for my domain). 
Is there exist some compiled flash to do this?

schema:
1.from current page I send event to flash
2. flash dispatches event to other flash instances, which send javascript event

Comment: Like, by using LocalConnection?

Comment: yes. maybe there is some library exist for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class to call functions of other swfs on the user's computer, even if they are in other browsers. You can then use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call JavaScript functions if you want,